# How to handle nested exceptions without dropping any information?

Tags: java, exception, nested

Often I have that kind of pattern: (Fictional example)

```
public void saveImage(Image image) throws ImageServiceException
{
    try
    {
        saveToDatabase(image); //private method saving image's meta data (id, name, infos etc.)
        saveToFile(image); //private method saving image's raw binary data
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        throw new ImageServiceException("Could not save image into database", ex);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        try
        {
            deleteFromDatabase(image);
        }
        catch(SQLException deletionEx) //exception is ignored !!!
        {
            throw new ImageServiceException("Could not save image on disk and could not delete image from database", ex);
        }

        throw new ImageServiceException("Could not save image on disk, database has been cleaned up", ex);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to save a database some infos about an image and then save the image on the disk. If it fails to be saved on the disk, I want to rollback what I did in the database. If that also fails, I'm not able to log both errors. I want to be able to keep all informations about what was doing on in that method. I've seen there's no `AggregateException` in Java as there's in C# but even that wouldn't do the job since I want to throw a checked exception.

How can I handle such cases?

Comment: As for the rollback I'd just use a transaction around that (e.g. via JTA) and just trigger a rollback when needed. No need to call things like `deleteFromDatabase(image)`.

Comment: @Thomas could the rollback trigger fails? If for instance the connection to the database is interupted while the image is saved on disk? If there's a chance of exception in that case, the problem is the same, just with a bit smarter example.

Comment: Losing the connection should cause the transaction to be rolled back on the db (or at least wait for commit/rollback until it times out). But you could still run into problems if you've written a file before committing and then the commit fails, so yes the case is probably similar. What you could do is use something like commands (e.g. one to write to the db, one to write the file, etc.) that can be undone and your exception/result could then list those commands and their status (rolled back, successful etc.).

Comment: @Thomas This whole question is an implementation detail, and I don't want it to change my method's signature. The `ImageService` may uses whatever method to save its image without creating problems, all I want is it to save an image or to throw an `ImageServiceException`.

Comment: Well, sometimes it's better to rethink your design instead of struggling with implementation details. Anyways, if all you want is something like an aggregate exception then you can implement `ImageServiceException` accordingly. You don't have to create an exception only when you're about to throw it and you don't have to throw an exception that's been created. So you could create an exception at the start (or some list/set to collect intermediate exceptions), collect any messages or errors you want and finally throw it or not (depending on whether any relevant error happend).

Comment: "keep all informations" what information? Why keep it?

Comment: @Raedwald All the thrown exceptions, to properly log them. This question is 2 years old